# COM object management in C++

Tags: c++, windows, com

Suppose you created COM object that represents all DVD drives in Windows system. You retrieved all necessary information from it and showed it to user. If there is "refresh" button somewhere (in case if some drives are added to the system) what is correct strategy to manage COM object?

1) Create class that manages DVD drive info. You create instance of this class when DVD Info window is created (with "refresh" button) and destroy it when window is destroyed. COM object is created in constructor and live until class instance is destroyed.

2) Create function (may be method of more general class) that creates COM object, retrieve all information and destroys it. It is called when DVD Info window is created and when user hits "refresh" button.

The bottom line is whether you should keep COM object if it is used frequently or "just in case"?. What is costly, keep COM object alive OR create and destroy it each time? If answer is quite deterministic, is it true for all Windows object? If no, how to know in which case which strategy is more appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule for this.

It's not very correct, but COM object for C++ is just an instance of a class. There is different ways how this objects are creating. It's more extensible operation in case of COM. But in case of CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER there is no very big costs for object creating if we are comparing with object creating with new in C++. So, i think that the answer for your question is the same as answer for question: If i don't know how long constructor of some class will be running too much, can i create the instances of such a class too frequently times?

But, again, If you think that call to CoGetClassObject() (CoCreateInstance()) is too expensive for you then try to save reference to newly created object as long as possible